# Jenkins .class files output

Tags: java, jenkins, continuous-integration, .class-file

I would like to know where Jenkins output the .class files it builds during a job, but I can't find it. Does anyone know where it is or how to set it ?

Comment: It depends on build tool. You can browse workspace of a project in Jenkins UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to jenkins home directory and open workspace. You will find all you need there

[image: Location of home directory]

You can hit /configure to view the Home directory.